# One to many relationship in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a database with tables Teachers,Subjects and Teachers_Subjects in my android sqlite database.My tables have structure as shown in the image.[image]

I need to query tables to get all subjects rows that are related to a single teacher.
 Initially I have the `_id` of the teacher.Using `teachers _id` I need to find the subjects.
According to me first I need to find all the rows in **Teachers_Subjects Table** related to a Teacher and then make other query using the resulted rows and Subjects Table with **JOIN statement** to get all rows related to that teacher.
I wanted to know is there any better way/query to accomplish this?If not then what should be the query for the solution mentioned above?

Comment: You can do it all in one step. Use a raw query with two inner joins.

Comment: @Leco Can you plz show me example query ...i would be very thankful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT Subjects.*
FROM Teachers_Subjects JOIN Subjects
                       ON Teachers_Subjects.subject_id = Subjects._id
WHERE Teachers_Subjects.teacher_id = ?
```